# how to establish a TCP connection of two nodes in different LANs using Java or any other pl

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, p2p

There are two restrictions on this question:

**Nodes do not have public IP addresses.** They are in different LANs. For example, A is in LAN1 with ip 192.168.0.100, B is in LAN2 with ip 10.0.0.2, the connection between A and B can't be established by invoking `new Socket("192.168.0.100",port)`

**Configuring routers or NAT is not practicable.** I mean that there is no port mapping from NAT to the node in LAN. I am thinking about how to implement a p2p chatting system ,in which any nodes can join at any time. All nodes have their  routers/NAT configured is impossible.And the ip addressof nodes can even change dynamically.

- Is it possible to establish a TCP connection of two nodes in
  different LANs under two restrictions above?
- If possible, how?
- If not, how to implement a p2p chatting system ? how can two nodes
  in different LANs communicate directly rather than transfer messages
  by a central server?

Comment: "Is it possible to establish a TCP connection of two nodes in different LANs under two restrictions above?"   no.  "If not, how to implement a p2p chatting system ? "  You can't.  That's like saying "How can I mail a letter to someone if I only know what state they live in?"

Comment: UPnP might help, but it still requires router configuration and/or compatible hardware.